# harmonic conjugate is unique up to a constant

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

$u: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is harmonic function.

If I let $w$ and $v$ both be harmonic conjugate of u, combining this with Cauchy Riemann equations, I can reach conclusion that w and v differ by a constant after some manipulations. However, the problem states that U is connected. (i.e. U is connected. Show that harmonic conjugates differ by a constant)

But, I didn't use the fact that U is connected in my proof. Could someone clarify to me where I need the fact that U is connected?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Let $V$ and $W$ be two connected components of $U$. Let $u\equiv 0$. Let $$v(z) = \begin{cases} 0 &, z\in V \\ 1 &, z \in W\\ 2 &, z \in U\setminus (V\cup W)\end{cases}$$ and $w \equiv 0$. The vanishing of the derivative(s) only tells you that the function is _locally_ constant.

Answer (score 1):

You can get $\nabla v\equiv \nabla w $, but to conclude that $v-w$ is constant, you need connected domain. Otherwise, see the counterexample given by  Daniel Fischer.

When the domain is connected, you can argue as follows: pick a point $p\in U$ and let $V=\{x\in U: u(x)-v(x) = u(p)-v(p)\}$. Show that $V$ is nonempty (contains $p$), closed (use continuity), and open (use  $\nabla v\equiv \nabla w$). The conclusion $V=U$ follows.